# Running sensors in simulation

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi. I am a new user to ROS and have some questions regarding the use of sensors in simulation.

I undrstand that in order to simulate a sensors, you need to write the gazebo extension for it in the robot's URDF file My doubts are mainly about the elements in the gazebo's extension block.

First of all, am I right to said that the controllers are what that operate the sensors in gazebo? So do I need to install drivers for sensors at all?

To use the controller, you need to choose the correct plugins, but where do we download the plugins from? The sensor's wiki page?

Lastly, how do we know what to include in the elements within the  element? So far what I did is just refer the code block from robots like turtlebot without understanding what each part is for.

I checked this [website](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/sensor), but it is still work in process.

Thank you.Pardon me if my questions sounds amatuerish.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/66/running-sensors-in-simulation/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/46079/queries-about-sensors-in-simulation/?answer=46177#post-id-46177) (from answers.ros) included here for completeness.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0